# scroll to div on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
                 <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html class="no-js" lang="en">
                    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Woodry</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?                    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
        <script   src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery
                    /1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
            $(document).scrollTop( $("#video").offset().top );  
             });
            </script>
            </head>
            <body class="wrapper">
        <div id="top">
            <img src="img/top.png">
     </div>
        <div id="video" class="video">
        <div id="deer"><img class="deer" src="img/deerb.png"></div>
        <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
        <source src="video/dust.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
            </video>
    </div>
    <div id="main" class="main">
        <img src="img/bottom.png">

        <div id="home"></div>
        <div id="shop"></div>
        <div id="contact"></div>
        </div>
             </body>
        </html>
```

Trying to scroll to the  on page load. The js function that I have doesnt seem to work. I have ran js tests to see if I am calling the js library correctly, which I am. Im doing something wrong. any help would be greatly appreciated.
UPDATED: I ran my HTML through the W3c validator and it passed.

Comment: has your div got an id of video? `<div id="video"></div>` not `div="video"`

Comment: y u ask without searching stackoverflow first? You create garbage duplicate data on the internet...

Comment: sounds like you have conflicting code somewhere that is firing after the alert that is scrolling back to the top

Comment: yes I have a <div id="video"> ((vide)) </div>

Comment: @Kyle_Bridges do you have any javascript errors?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h6fhr/4/ here is the fiddle it says i have no js errors.

Comment: @Kyle_Bridges no jquery loaded... here you go http://jsfiddle.net/h6fhr/5/ Please tell me you have loaded jquery in your actual HTML code...

Comment: yes the script tag is right above the code:

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>    I even ran a js checker to see if the library was loading.

Comment: @Kyle_Bridges do you have any javascript errors?

Comment: No, when I ran it in fiddle it said there was no js errors the only js I have is the command that is shown in the code

Comment: @adween I just ran my HTML through W3C markup validation and it passed

Comment: @Kyle_Bridges that's not what i asked... Are there any javascript errors when you run your page. We know that the fiddle works. The issue is does your page or does it have errors. the only thing i can think of is your jquery is not working. try downloading a copy of jquery and linking to that in your code and see if that works.

Comment: @adween I know, i stated that i tested the js. Here is the js tester        if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is loaded => print the version
    alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to scroll to a div, but your js code is looking for an `id`, so it should be

```
id="video"
```

This should work then.

**Edit:** Just checked the code, I used this:

```
$(function() { 
 $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#video').offset().top}, 1000);
});
```

This works for me. Your bottom image is 18MB (which is big), so you might want to try to wait until the *page* (and not the *DOM*) has loaded with:

```
$(window).load(function() {
// code here
});
```

Comment: we never see his div markup, so I think it's quite an assumption that this is the issue. from what I can see, the code fires before the document has finished loaded, hence calling the function within a document "ready" check, would work

Comment: my id selector is correct. I do have the script code in my header. Is that causing it to fire premature?

Comment: @Kyle_Bridges you script can go anywhere on the page after you have loaded jquery. `$(function(){` tells the script to wait for the page to load before executing so no it will not be firing prematurely. Your issue is elsewhere not with the code you have posted. please see my answer

Comment: @Kyle_Bridges is it possible for you to share the page, so I can check properly?

Comment: @Kyle_Bridges I just updated my answer. Check the size of your images and use the window load function to wait until the whole page has loaded.

Comment: @paranoia sry will you post the completed code you used? I tried putting my code under //code here and it doesnt work. Also do you think the picture size is too big? I was worried about that.

Comment: @Kyle_Bridges sure, I just put an example in my post (http://codepen.io/pirrera/pen/ABjGp/). I copied your code and just removed the images and set background colors to see what is happening). Your code is working just fine, the problem is that the code is being executed before the full image has loaded (which causes the browser to bounce back on top)

Comment: @paranoia Hey, thank you so much for doing that! I really appreciate it, honestly! It worked perfectly! Thanks again!!!! have a good one!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have issues elsewhere in your code.

Here is a fiddle that has what you currently have working http://jsfiddle.net/A5uyX/

```
$(function() { 
    $(document).scrollTop( $("#video").offset().top );
});
```

I would look at any other `scrollTop` functions or if you have a hash value in your url that is pointing somewhere else on the page maybe.

Have you loaded jquery? try adding this to you head section before your script block

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

from looking at the code you have just popped on the only thing i can see is that you have a css link not fully closed. try closing it and see if that helps. not 100% sure what the link should be but it is this line

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
```

Comment: that fiddle is what I used the first time. Honestly you could be right.  I just dont see how it would effect it. Its the only js code im using and im using google's js library.

Comment: @Kyle_Bridges you would need to post some more code so we can try to see the issue then. Currently this question doesn't have enough info to answer as your code works...

Comment: I have the google script tag there, and I deleted the google fonts link, and still no change. Thanks for helping though! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).scrollTop( $("#video").offset().top );  
    });
</script>
```

And add the attribute `id="video"` to your html tag if you didn't already.

Comment: `$(function() {` is the same as `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: Are you sure? Because I already had problems with ´$(function() {´ and replacing it by ´$(document).ready(function() {´ solved my problems...

Perhaps not every version of jQuery supports the same functions or not every browser is supporting the same functions...

Comment: Anyway for me, it solved already problems and perhaps it's working for Kyle_Bridges too

Comment: Ive tried the above code and its not working for some reason. I had a typo im my comment, my id is labelled correctly. Thanks for responding!

Comment: Can you please add a JSFiddle to your question with your code, so it's easier for us to find an solution for your problem

Comment: I made an JSFiddle with your code and it works perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/LJQY3/1/

Answer (score 1):

Why not using a simple anchor ?

```
<div id="foo">
</div>
```

And

```
yourlink.html#foo
```

I think that works.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin :smooth scrolling, you can find it here:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

From Docs:

$.scrollTo(...);//the plugin will take care of this

Answer (score 0):

Try with jQuery animate():

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#video").offset().top }, 800);
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(document).scrollTop( $("#video").offset().top );
});
```

Comment: please read the following page http://api.jquery.com/ready/ `$(function() {` is the same as `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: This answer is hard to read because of the positioning of the round braces. At first sight the section `ready(function() {` has a missing close brace but more study show the brace is on the last line. I much prefer layout where spaces and line breaks make the code easy to read.